# chromium aura GPU accelerating

Tags: chromium

Can any one tell me how to create a pixmap for Aura chromium OS.As i want to enable gpu accelerating for my browser.
please guide me how to proceed further.Any ideas and suggestion to overcome this issue.Is there any API available can any one share a sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you run like this does it run slower
    chromium-browser --use-gl=osmesa  --user-data-dir=/home/user1

Try to pass some flags.

```
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
```